# How to add custom properties to a webpart in Office 365

Tags: 2013, 2010, sharepoint-online, office-365

I added a content editor webpart to my page, and updated its content link to a html page

Then I exported the `content editor` webpart and changed title etc

Now I want to add a custom property to it by changing the exported `dwp` file

[image]

I tried the below code

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<WebPart xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/WebPart/v2">
  <Title>Announcements</Title>
  <FrameType>Default</FrameType>
  <Description>Allows authors to enter rich text content.</Description>
  <ListName>Allow users to add list name</ListName>
```

I tried to add a custom field called `ListName`.

How can I do it?

Comment: Hi,  I think you should derive the content editor web part as a visual web part then add the quick parts.

Comment: I am trying to do in office365

Comment: I am not entirely sure but you might need to develop and add-in and add custom properties to an add-in part.